# multiline string in .vimrc

Tags: vim

I want to create a new function in vim that pastes something like

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
</html>
```

into the current buffer. How do I write this as a multiline string? As single lines I would have to write

```
0put="<html>"
0put="<head>"
0put="</head>"
0put="</html>"
```

Comment: You should look at the implementation of [SnipMate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim) and/or [Sparkup](https://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup) or similar plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like putting the linebreak character between them, `\n` will do just fine